# Minimize using scrolldown

Tags: 16.04, launcher, mouse-scroll

I can scroll up on an open app in the launcher to restore a window. Is there any way to minimize by scrolling down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll feature in the Unity launcher is not about restoring or minimizing windows. It is for scrolling through the open windows for that application. If the app only has one window, then that's the only one that will open up, when scrolling. If it has multiple windows open, scrolling on that apps icon will cycle focus through the open windows.